# Pandas: Reset index for non unique index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

|  | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x1 | 0.20 |
| 0 | x1 | 0.40 |
| 0 | x1 | 0.34 |
| 3 | x2 | 0.12 |
| 3 | x2 | 0.13 |
| 4 | x3 | 0.19 |
| 4 | x3 | 0.23 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["x1", 0.2], ["x1", 0.4], ["x1", 0.34], ["x2", 0.12], ["x2", 0.13], ["x3", 0.19], ["x3", 0.239]],  index = [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 4], columns= ["Name", "Value"])
```

I would like to reset the index to get the following DataFrame:

|  | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x1 | 0.20 |
| 0 | x1 | 0.40 |
| 0 | x1 | 0.34 |
| 1 | x2 | 0.12 |
| 1 | x2 | 0.13 |
| 2 | x3 | 0.19 |
| 2 | x3 | 0.23 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["x1", 0.2], ["x1", 0.4], ["x1", 0.34], ["x2", 0.12], ["x2", 0.13], ["x3", 0.19], ["x3", 0.239]],  index = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], columns= ["Name", "Value"])
```

As this does not seem possible with the reset_index() function, what would be best way to achieve this reindexing?

The DataFrame results from using explode() and filtering NaN values. I want to reset the index after filtering to make it easier to loop over the exploded values later on. Notice that I don't want to use the "Name" column as the index, as indexing by string seems to be extremly slow for larger data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.set_axis(pd.factorize(df['Name'])[0].tolist())
```

Or:

```
df.index = pd.factorize(df['Name'])[0]
```

---

```
  Name  Value
0   x1  0.200
0   x1  0.400
0   x1  0.340
1   x2  0.120
1   x2  0.130
2   x3  0.190
2   x3  0.239
```